# Max of all columns based on distinct first column

Tags: bash

How do I change the code if I have more than two columns. Let's say the data is like this

```
ifile.dat
1   10  15
3   34  20
1   4   22
3   32  33
5   3   46
2   2   98
4   20  100
3   13  23
4   50  65
1   40  76
2   20  22
```

How do I achieve this?

```
ofile.dat
1   40  76
2   20  98
3   34  33
4   50  100
5   3   46
```

I mean the max of each column by comparing first column. Thanks.

Here is what I have tried(on a sample file with 13columns). But the highest value is not coming up this way.

```
cat input.txt | sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr -k3,3nr -k4,4nr -k5,5nr -k6,6nr -k7,7nr -k8,8nr -k9,9nr -k10,10nr -nrk11,11 -nrk12,12 -nrk13,13 | sort -k1,1 -u
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on `sort`, you could switch over to something more robust like `awk`:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) if (a[$1][i]<$i){a[$1][i]=$i}} END{n=asorti(a, asorted); for(col1 in asorted){print col1, a[col1][2], a[col1][3]}}' input.txt
```

That's a mouthful. It breaks down like:

1. Before processing the file set the `PROCINFO` setting of `sorted_in` to `@val_num_asc` since we will be sorting the contents of an array by its index which will be numeric: (`BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"}`)
2. Loop through each field in the record `for(i=2;i<=NF;++i)`
3. Test to see if the current value is greater than the stored value in the array which has as its index the first field's value. If it is greater, then store it in place of whatever is currently held in the array for that index at that fields position: (`if (a[$1][i]<$i){a[$1][i]=$i}`)
4. When done processing all of the records, sort the array into new array `asorted`: (`END{n=asorti(a, asorted);`)
5. Iterate through the array and print each element (`for(col1 in asorted){print col1, a[col1][2], a[col1][3]}`)

There may be a more elegant way to do this in `awk`, but this will do the trick.

---

Example:

```
:~$ cat test
1   10  15
3   34  20
1   4   22
3   32  33
5   3   46
2   2   98
4   20  100
3   13  23
4   50  65
1   40  76
2   20  22
:~$ awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) if (a[$1][i]<$i){a[$1][i]=$i}} END{n=asorti(a, asorted); for(col1 in asorted){print col1, a[col1][2], a[col1][3]}}' test
1 40 76
2 20 98
3 34 33
4 50 100
5 3 46
```

Comment: Thank you. Here is an error that comes up on ubuntu & mac.

    `awk: BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) if (a[$1][i]<$i){a[$1][i]=$i}} END{n=asorti(a, asorted); for(col1 in asorted){print col1, a[col1][2], a[col1][3]}}
    awk:                                                                            ^ syntax error`

Comment: I just tried this on a slightly older version of Ubuntu and it worked, but... it might just be `awk` versions. Try flipping that over to `gawk` since `asorti` is definitely `gawk` function and see if it makes it happy.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Still the same. The error is being pointed to " >>> if(a[$1][ <<< "

Comment: This this might be a dead end, unless someone with more posix compliance knowledge steps in to spot the error.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) if (a[$1][i]<$i){a[$1][i]=$i}} END{n=asorti(a, asorted); for(col1 in asorted){print col1, a[col1][2], a[col1][3]}}' test
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) if >>>  (a[$1][ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`